# Strange behavior Org-mode latex export label

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Currently, I've experienced some strange behavior of latex labelling of org-mode exported file.

Normally, I use the label style like `#+NAME: fig:name` for figure and table labelling, which corresponds to the label in the LaTeX file as `\label{fig:name}`, and works fine with the `org-ref` reference style `[[ref:fig:name]]`. The sections I do not intentionally label will be added a label like `\label{sec:1}` in LaTeX file.

However, I found sometimes the org-mode exported file will generate a different label style like `\label{sec:org76fd1b6}}`, and the `#+NAME:` tag is not correctly translated to the label I want. Indeed, putting something like `#+CAPTION: label:fig:name XXXX` still works, but looks much uglier.

The question is: **how is such behavior invoked and how to avoid it?**

Tested system: OS X 10.11, Emacs 25.1, org-mode 20161102 and org-ref 20161101

Comment: Does `(setq org-latex-prefer-user-labels t)` help?

Comment: Interestingly I tried to evaluate this variable but seemed it did not exist. Do I need to require additional packages?

Comment: The docline says that it's defined in `ox-latex.el`. You could probably use `setq-default` instead, or set it after loading `ox-latex`? But to see its doc, try to `C-h v` on it, after exporting from Org to LaTeX once.

Answer (score 3):

The solution that has (so far) worked, is to reference the figure as `[[fig:name]]` in the text. The current Org-mode has been smart enough to translate this correctly. For sections etc, you could use a [`CUSTOM_ID`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html) and refer to `[[#section_id]]`.

Alternatively, use the LaTeX-commands `\label{fig:name}` in your text and refer to it as `\ref{fig:name}`.